# mat-sidenav-container breakpoint override

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a mat-sidenav-container
Is there a way to override the breakpoint so the drawer does not automatically open when the screen gets to a certain width?

Under 600 px - shows hamburger
[image]

Currently @ 600px it opens automatically
I only want it to open if the user clicks on the hamburger
Over 600px - Stays open
[image]

```
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav
      #drawer
      class="sidenav"
      fixedInViewport="false"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
      <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let i of navItems">
        <a *ngIf="(i.navText) && (i.router) && (i.showYNNav === 'Y')"
           mat-list-item [routerLink]="[i.router]">{{i.navText}}</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button
          type="button"
          aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
          mat-icon-button
          (click)="drawer.toggle()"
          *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span>
          <a class="mat-toolbar mat-primary homeLink"
            [routerLink]="['/']"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <span>Site Name Here</span>
          </a>
        </span>
      </mat-toolbar>
      <div class="componentMargin">
        <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
      </div>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

In the .ts

```
isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = 
this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
     map(result => result.matches)
    );
```

Comment: can you share a code?

Comment: sharing your html and typescript will help tremendously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you figure it out right after you post the question

Hard coding the attributes seems to do the trick
Instead of using the isHandset$ observable that watches the breakpoints

```
attr.role="dialog"
mode="over"
opened="false"
```

Comment: If you're electing to hard code the brackets, you don't need the [ and ]. This tell's Angular to evaluate the value as an expression, which you don't need since you're hard coding. Glad you got it figured out!